# Limitando funções de acordo com o nível de acesso

Tags: c#, sql-server, login

Tenho o form `MenuPrincipal` e  o `FormLogon`, onde este último, após realizar as consultas de validação de login, chama o o Menu e fecha. Preciso limitar alguns botões e controles conforme o nível de acesso desse usuário que acabou de logar, tanto como guardar seu ID em uma variável. Há como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é possível, o ideal seria criar uma classe de controle pra isso, mas se preferir as variáveis, após chamar o menu basta fazer um select na tabela de usuários trazendo os dados que precisa e guardá-los em variáveis, depois faça um IF ocultando estes botões e controles que não quer que ele tenha acesso.